# Why doesn't wbk.wks.Range work? It works when I use the workbook and worksheet names

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following definition in the beginning of my macro

```
'Define This Workbook
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

'Define Main Sheet
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Sheet2
```

I don't understand why the following line of code doesn't work. I get the error message "object doesnt support this property or method".

```
lastRow = wbk.wks.Range("B:B").Find("Timmar", [B1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
```

So instead I have to write the following lines of codes. They work:

```
wbk.Activate
wks.Activate
lastRow = Range("B:B").Find("Timmar", [B1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
```

Do you understand why my original approach does not work?

Comment: `wbk.wks.Range("B:B")`-->`wks.Range("B:B")`. `wbk` is `Workbook` object and it indeed doesn't support property with name `wks`: check it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301167(v=office.15).aspx). If you want to specify that `wks` belongs to `wbk`, use `Set wks = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet2")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment above, change

```
wbk.wks.Range("B:B")
```

to

```
wks.Range("B:B")
```

`wbk` is `Workbook` object and it indeed doesn't support property with name `wks`. Check it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301167%28v=office.15%29.aspx).
If you want to specify that `wks` belongs to `wbk`, use something like this:

```
Set wks = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

Also if range `wks.Range("B:B")` doesn't contain cells with `Timmer` value - you'd get runtime error, since you're trying to get `.Row` property of *unfound* cell (when result of `.Find` is `Nothing`). Use this one instead:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set rng = wks.Range("B:B").Find("Timmar", wks.[B1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    lastRow = rng.Row
Else
    lastRow = 1 ' change to suit
End If
```

Comment: Can I use the following line, Set wks = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet2"), but refer to the codename instead of the name?

Comment: here is a little hack: `Set wks = wbk.Worksheets(CStr(wbk.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet2").Properties("Name")))
`